# Different behavior of Power between versions 9 and 10

Tags: functions, version-10

Rather by accident I've noticed that the following trivial code produces different output in *Mathematica* 9 and 10:

```
-((-1)^n)
```

*Mathematica* 9:

$-(-1)^n$

*Mathematica* 10:

$(-1)^{(n+1)}$

Both forms are of course correct, but this a bit annoying if one uses the same set of unit tests to check the code against both versions. Can someone confirm this? Does someone know the reasoning behind this change?